# django form add css to ModelMultipleChoiceFIeld

Tags: python, django

How exactly do I add css to a forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField
I tried to pass in `attrs={'class' : 'foo'}`
But it's failing saying `"__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attrs'"`

```
my_list = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(label='List', required=False, queryset=[])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the widget that needs the attrs, not the form field.

```
my_list = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    label='List',
    required=False,
    queryset=[],
    widget=SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'foobar'}))
```